# Methods that can only be called by one thread at a time

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I have a function that is used by multiple threads. Because of its nature, this function should only ever called once at a time. Multiple threads calling the function at the same time could be bad.

If the function is in use by a thread, other threads should have to wait for it to be free.

My background isn't coding so I'm not sure, but I believe this is called "locking" in the jargon? I tried Googling it up but did not find a simple example for Python3.

A simplified case:

```
def critical_function():
    # How do I "lock" this function?
    print('critical operation that should only be run once at a time')

def threaded_function():
    while True:
        # doing stuff and then
        critical_function()

for i in range(0, 10):
    threading.Thread(target=threaded_function).start()
```

Comment: So what do you want to happen when a 2nd thread tries to call the function? Should it throw an error? Should it wait for the first thread to finish?

Comment: @Rawing - last line of the first paragraph of my question `If the function is in use by a thread, other threads should have to wait for it to be free.` I'll put it on its own line to make it clearer.

Comment: See this, http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm

Comment: @Sush I've checked it up but that doesn't seem to apply to python 3. Googling `python3 mutex` gives https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html but the examples in that documentation are not clear for a guy without background in these kind of things. It also doesn't look like `mutex` library is a thinkg in python3.

Comment: Look up a mutex, I think that that's what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from threading import Lock
critical_function_lock = Lock()

def critical_function():
    with critical_function_lock:
        # How do I "lock" this function?
        print('critical operation that should only be run once at a time')
```